# How to stop #error from appearing in cell with ="" string in gsheets

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I imported a massive file into a google spreadsheet and one of the columns has cells that contain:

=+this +is +a +keyword +in +google +adwords

The problem is that this results in #ERROR! because it is not wrapped in quotation marks. The error stops showing when I add them:

="+this +is +a +keyword +in +google +adwords"

Instead of doing this manually for 1000's of rows, how can I automatically add these quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the error message by prepending the strings that starts with an equal operator or a plus operator with an apostrophe (`'`). You could use Find and Replace to replace `=`. See [Search and use find and replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?hl=en).

Use "Search using regular expressions" and "Also search within formulas" to only replace the starting `=` by `'=`. The regular expression to use on the Find box is `^=`.

[image]

Al alternative is to use Google Apps Script. See 
[Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)